ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) could not parse resource []
As a part of my task in the "The Basics of Google Cloud Compute" course, I am required to enter the following code on the shell:-
gcloud compute instances create backend \
    --zone=$ZONE \
    --machine-type=e2-standard-2 \
    --tags=backend \
   --metadata=startup-script-url=https://storage.googleapis.com/fancy-store-$DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID/startup-script.sh

However, the following error comes up:-
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) could not parse resource []

I have tried retyping the entire thing, changing the amount of spaces and all, but in vain. The previous code-blocks (which initialized variables, set up the environment, etc.) ran smoothly according to the course, so I don't think there's any problem there.

Web search points you to Google's documentation which walks you thru this https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance
